How to fix datarow/datacolumn RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
I am using Flutter datatable.
I have a single column and I want to add multiple rows.
I initialized a column and row, but I am getting RangeError (index).
I no longer have empty column and row. Could you please advise.
if I do list.add:
myDataColumnList.add(DataColumn(label: Text('My Column Heading')));
myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[DataCell(placeholder: true,Text('-'))]));

Then I see and nothing else happens:

My code:
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DataColumn> myDataColumnList = [];
  List<DataRow> myDataRowList = [];
  int i = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeColumnsRows();
    super.initState();
  }

  initializeColumnsRows(){
    myDataColumnList[0]=DataColumn(label: Text('My Column Heading'));
    myDataRowList[0]=DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[DataCell(placeholder: true,Text('-'))]);
  }

  addToList(){
   setState(() {
     myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[DataCell(placeholder: true,Text('x1: '+i.toString()))]));
   });
   i = i + 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Container(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(onPressed: addToList, child: const Text('addToList')),
                  Table(children: [TableRow(children: <Widget>[ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return DataTable(columns: myDataColumnList, rows: myDataRowList);
                  },)])]),],),),);})));}
}


You're attempting to access indices in empty lists (myDataColumnList[0] and myDataRowList[0]) which will result in a range error because the lists are initially empty.
To fix this, you should use .add() to add elements to the lists rather than trying to assign values to non-existing indices.
Something like that :
initializeColumnsRows(){
  myDataColumnList.add(DataColumn(label: Text('My Column Heading')));
  myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[DataCell(Text('-'))]));
}

EDIT:
I suppose you want a running example. Cause my answer fix your problem (i.e :How to fix datarow/datacolumn RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)
BUT this is not the only problem.

Removed the Table and ListView.builder around the DataTable. Instead, directly included the DataTable in the column.

The addToList method now properly updates the state and appends new rows to the myDataRowList.


Full code here :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DataColumn> myDataColumnList = [];
  List<DataRow> myDataRowList = [];
  int i = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeColumnsRows();
  }

  void initializeColumnsRows() {
    myDataColumnList.add(DataColumn(label: const Text('My Column Heading')));
    myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[const DataCell(Text('-'))]));
  }

  void addToList() {
    setState(() {
      myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text('x1: ' + i.toString()))
      ]));
      i = i + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(onPressed: addToList, child: const Text('Add to List')),
            DataTable(
              columns: myDataColumnList,
              rows: myDataRowList,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


This is good suggestion, but I don't get anything. I see the screenshot and nothing happens. Please look at my original post. Thank You

That s not a suggestion, it s an answer. You provide a screenshot of your ide console. Where is the application ?

Eric! Your code works! Thank You

Can you choose my answer as the good one ?

I just did! Thank You
